# Restrict Google Drive to only allow an office IP address access

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

Is there a way to block home access from an office Google Drive? We want users to be at the office physically and use the office router to login into the office Google Drive.

---

Currently we have a file server(suppose you could do this with any type of pc) that sync with google to a local folder (using google's backup & sync), then shares the local folder to the LAN. So if you are not connected to the LAN you don't have access.

This does however require one of your pc's to act as a server, hopefully there is a better/easier soluiton

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 14 times. I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to [sf] as it requires knowledge about networking and understanding about administering file storage services in a business/corporate setting.

Answer (score 1):

setup a network mask may help. You can find more details here [Network Mapping Results](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6369487?hl=en). You will have to set up Single Sign On to be able to create a network mask with G suite.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the correct G Suite account you can restrict by IP, device etc.

I have not needed to do this but it is all in G Suite admin / devices